# Understanding PHP code includes

Tags: php

I am pretty new to PHP. I am going through a website and am trying to find a source of some of the content and have come across what looks like where the source is, but I cannot decipher the code. Can someone help me understand what this means?

```
<?php

if (is_file($office_file)) 
    include($office_file);
echo do_shortcode(ob_get_clean());
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your code and added comments that (hopefully) explain what is going on.

```
<?php
if (is_file($office_file)) // check if $office_file is a valid file
    include($office_file); // the check passes, so now include the contents of that file inline
echo do_shortcode(ob_get_clean()); // not enough context to know really what this does, but it looks like its printing the result of parsing 'shortcode' from an output buffer
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot and I found my source file!